# Finding screen resolution in IE10 on Windows Phone 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to make a web app for windows phone 8 that requires the full screen resolution

It seems there is no way to discover this

Using: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />`

This will always be 320

Using javascript `screen.width` returns 320

Using javascript `screen.availWidth` returns 320

I have put together some code that seems to be working for now:

JavaScript:

```
window.devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || screen.deviceXDPI / screen.logicalXDPI;
var actualWidth = screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio;
actualWidth = actualWidth - (actualWidth % 2);
var actualHeight = screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio;
actualHeight = actualHeight - (actualHeight % 2);

// TEMP FIX!
if(actualHeight == 1282){
    actualHeight = 1280;
}

$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
        // portrait
        width = actualWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
    }else{
        // landscape
        width = actualHeight;
        height = window.innerHeight;
    }

    $('html').css('width', width);
    $('body').css('width', width);
}).trigger('resize');
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    @-ms-viewport { width: 720px; }
}
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    @-ms-viewport { width: 1280px; }
}
```

Is there a better way to find the true screen resolution on windows phone 8?

Any help/advice on this problem would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript, this code will work on any device:

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately this isnt the answer

On a HTC 8X (720x1280):

If i use this with the viewport this gives 320x521

If i use this without the viewport this gives 1024x1667